# React Redux - boolean value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want process a plain boolean value with my Redux store. But this value results into undefined on every dispatch event. Does any of you see why?

I have the following setup:

### reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    canSwipe: true
};

export default function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CAN_SWIPE: {
        console.log(action.payload.canSwipe) // This logs true or false - works!
        return action.payload.canSwipe
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

### actions.js

```
export const setSwipeState = canSwipe => ({ type: CAN_SWIPE, payload: { canSwipe } });
```

### component for dispatching

```
function MapOverlay({setSwipeState}) {
    const zoom = 5;
    return (
        <Map
            onMovestart={() => setSwipeState(false)}
            onMoveend={() => setSwipeState(true)}
        >
            {...}
        </Map>
    )
}

export default connect(null, {setSwipeState})(MapOverlay);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reducer should return data which must be compliant with your initial state:

```
const initialState = {
    canSwipe: true
};
```

So you need to change your reducer to respect this structure:

```
switch (action.type) {
        case CAN_SWIPE: {
        console.log(action.payload.canSwipe) // This logs true or false - works!
        return {canSwipe: action.payload.canSwipe}
        }
```